# Rails query random models until an attribute reaches a quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a exercise model which has two attributes: title and points. The goal is getting a list of exercises until to reach an amount of points fixed previously. For example:

```
TABLE: exercises

title | points
==============
aaaaa | 3
bbbbb | 5
ccccc | 10
ddddd | 10
eeeee | 5
fffff | 3


@points <= 14

RESULT

aaaaa | 3
bbbbb | 5
eeeee | 5

or

aaaaa | 3
ccccc | 10

or 

ccccc | 10
fffff | 3

... etc ...
```

Somthing like:

`select_values("SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE SUM(points) < 14)`

Comment: So do you need all variations, or just one?

Comment: Actually I'd like different results every time I run the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following SQL should work in MySQL.

```
SET @psum := 0;
SELECT t1.* FROM (
    SELECT m.*,  
          (@psum := @psum + m.points) AS cumulative_points
    FROM (SELECT title, points from Exercises r ORDER BY RAND()) m
) t1 
WHERE t1.cumulative_points <= 14;
```

However the ActiveRecord query would look a bit messy. E.g. something like:

```
random_exercises = Exercise.transaction do
  Exercise.connection.execute("SET @psum = 0;")
  # this is returned, because it's the last line in the block
  Exercise.find_by_sql(%Q|
    SELECT t1.* FROM (
        SELECT m.*,  
              (@psum := @psum + m.points) AS cumulative_points
        FROM (SELECT title, points from exercises r ORDER BY RAND()) m
    ) t1 
    WHERE t1.cumulative_points <= 14
  |)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
Exercise.where(...).group(...).having('SUM(points) < ?', predefined_value)
```

Or, in your case, simply:

```
Exercise.having('SUM(points) < ?', predefined_value)
```